# why giving a tab master window and adding it to tk.notebook() result as the tab was given notebook as a master window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm currently a noob to tkinter as i made this code. so kindly ignore any foolishness if found.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Menu


win=tk.Tk()
win.title('Tabs GUI')
tab_control=ttk.Notebook(win)

tab1=ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1,text='Tab 1')
tab_control.grid()

tab2=ttk.Frame(win)                                       #1
tab_control.add(tab2,text='Tab 2')


menuBar = Menu(tab1)                             #2
win.config(menu=menuBar)

# Add menu items
fileMenu = Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)
fileMenu.add_command(label="New")
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit")
menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

# Add another Menu to the Menu Bar and an item
helpMenu = Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)
helpMenu.add_command(label="About")
menuBar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpMenu)


ttk.Label(tab2, text="Choose a number:").grid(column=0, row=0)
numberChosen = ttk.Combobox(tab2, width=8)
numberChosen['values'] = (1, 2, 4, 42, 100)
numberChosen.grid(column=0, row=1)
numberChosen.current(0)


chVarDis = tk.IntVar()
check1 = tk.Checkbutton(tab2, text="Disabled", variable=chVarDis, state='disabled')
check1.select()
check1.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=tk.W)                 

chVarUn = tk.IntVar()
check2 = tk.Checkbutton(tab2, text="UnChecked", variable=chVarUn)
check2.deselect()
check2.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=tk.W )


win.mainloop()
```

now the first problem is that on #1 i gave 'tab2' master window i.e 'win', then added it to the notebook but it acts like i gave it notebook() as a master window because 'tab1' and 'tab2' are functioning same. And the second problem is why 'combobox' is auto-focused when i open 'tab2'. and the same goes for `Menu()` #2, i've given it parent `tab1` yet it is displayed in top level window `win`

Comment: Which widget is the master is only used in `pack`, `grid` and `place`. Adding a tab does not care which widget is master.

Comment: The combobox is focused because it's the first interactive widget you put into tab2. If you put a button or entry above it (in the code, not necessarily above it on the screen) then that will be selected. You can also use `focus()` to set the focus to any widget you like.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your first comment and why does `Menu()` also behaves like this. Second one solved half problem

Comment: can you explain your first comment a little more

Comment: You can use *any* widget (or none) as the master when you are making tabs, the Notebook does not care. Menu and Canvas and others don't care either, the only place where it matters what widget you give as master is when you use `pack`, `grid`, or `place`. And even then you can override the master with the `in_` argument.

Comment: `tab2=ttk.Frame(some_label_instance)` or `tab2=ttk.Frame()` would work too. Notebook does not use the master information.

Comment: that solved it.